# Multiple side menus and one tab ionic

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, ionic-framework

I want to make a tab app but with different sidemenus depending on the tab chosen ! Can someone give me directives on how I can do that ? Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who would need it, I found a way to do it: we define our menu and in the `ion-side-menu-content` there is an `ion-nav-view`, so it's there that we include the `ion-tabs tag` that contains our tabs.

So the other menus can be defined with the same tab.

*[Translated from French by [Google](https://translate.google.com)]*